# How do I turn a comma separated string column to individual factors with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```py
                              movie                                             url                   genres
0  Paranormal Activity: Next of Kin  /movie-reviews/paranormal-activity-next-of-kin  Horror,Mystery,Thriller
1                           Antlers                          /movie-reviews/antlers     Drama,Horror,Mystery
2                Heart of Champions               /movie-reviews/heart-of-champions                    Drama
3                        13 Minutes                       /movie-reviews/13-minutes    Action,Drama,Thriller
4                      Tango Shalom                     /movie-reviews/tango-shalom      Comedy,Drama,Family
```

Each movie has multiple genres, and I would like to see all the unique genres. I tried doing this:

```py
>>> df['genres'].unique()
array(['Horror,Mystery,Thriller', 'Drama,Horror,Mystery', 'Drama',
       'Action,Drama,Thriller', 'Comedy,Drama,Family'], dtype=object)
```

It returns an array of comma-separated items, and not the individual items themselves. How can I do this?

I have thought of converting the dataset from wide to long, with each genre in its own row but that would expand the dataset to rows that would be too many to handle.

Comment: This would be easy in a SQL database. Perhaps that's the answer - use a different tool.

Comment: @tdelaney Any way to convert this into one with Python and continue querying data within my code? I'm using this dataset for some analysis and I would like to have everything in one place.

Comment: [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is a single file database and is part of the python standard lib. You can go on disk or do `con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")` for an in-memory db. If on disk, its persistent, so you can decouple your data reading and data processing code.

Comment: @tdelaney I will look into this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `split` then `explode`

```
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.split(',')
out = df.explode('genres')
out = out.drop_duplicates('genres')
```

Comment: great answer! I think you could add `.unique()`to avoid repetition of genres

Comment: It would help to explain what explode does. Poster doesn't want a row per genre, but that's what s/he will get.

Comment: +1 to what @tdelaney said, but its still a good answer. It does increase the number of rows by almost three times and results in significant slowing though.

Comment: if you just want a unique set of genres, then you can do `df['genres'].str.split(',').explode().unique()`